# Footer consisting of two right triangles

Tags: css, footer

I'm making a website and I want the footer to look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9sFc.jpg

It's basically two triangles on top of each other. I've tried to make triangles like this:

```
#triangle-bottomleft {
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-bottom: 100px solid red;
border-right: 100px solid transparent;
}
```

But because the width depends on how many pixels you put in the border-right, I cannot use width: 100%.

Any Alternatives?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily achieve this with gradients:

```css
.footer {
  height:100px;
  background:
   linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49.5%,blue 50%),
   linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 49.5%,green 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
</div>
```

You can also adjust the size if you don't want the triangle to be full width:

```css
.footer {
  height:100px;
  background:
   linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49.5%,blue 50%) right/80% 100% no-repeat,
   linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 49.5%,green 50%) left/80% 100% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
</div>
```