# CSS element different height on element's side

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to get my desired output using css or jQuery without rotating the element?

[I wanted this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpZ0g.png)

Comment: Show us what you've tried and what failed, i am pretty sure the answer is already on this site, and one search away with good keywords. Also, it depends on what you are tring to achieve, but yes it is possible.

Comment: duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51749041/footer-consisting-of-two-right-triangles/51749101#51749101 ... simply keep on triangle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Footer consisting of two right triangles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51749041/footer-consisting-of-two-right-triangles)

Comment: How can I add gradient color to that?

Answer (score 0):

Without completely understanding your objective I'm assuming you're trying to create shapes without using the rotation properly. This method shows you how to create shapes with CSS3 :) Hope that helps!

https://www.cssportal.com/css3-shapes/

For example this creates a parallelogram:

```
#parallelogram {
   width: 130px; 
   height: 75px;
   background: blue;
   /* Skew */
   -webkit-transform: skew(20deg); 
   -moz-transform: skew(20deg); 
   -o-transform: skew(20deg);
   transform: skew(20deg);
}
```